# Ngrx Effect is called indefinitely

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I wrote Effect for loading category items from API, but my effect is called indefinitely. What I should do to:

1. Load list of categories only once.
2. If API does not respond, list of categories is empty.

I note that the categories are loaded correctly, but request is executed indefinitely.

Below I put the code:

**category.effect.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class CategoryEffects {

  @Effect()
  getAll$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
    .ofType(category.LOAD)
    .startWith(new category.LoadAction([]))
    .switchMap(() => {
      return this._categoriesService.getAllCategories()
        .map(categories => new category.LoadAction(categories))
        .catch(() => of(new category.LoadAction([])));
    });

  constructor(private actions$: Actions, private _categoriesService: CategoriesService) {
    console.log('CategoryEffects constructor')
  }
}
```

**categories.service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class CategoriesService {
  private API_PATH = 'https://private-xxx.apiary-mock.com/categories';

  constructor(private http: Http) {}

  getAllCategories(): Observable<Category[]> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.API_PATH}`)
      .map(res => res.json() || []);
  }

}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  //...
  imports: [
    //...
    EffectsModule.run(CategoryEffects)
  ],
  //...
})
```

Comment: is LoadAction(Array<>) method maybe returns that same LOAD event that is waiting for? that could be a reason for endless loading of that effect

Comment: I think @KresoJurisic is on to something. Post the code for `category.LoadAction`